# how to add submenu to "Open With" menu form org.eclipse.ui.menu extenstion point

Tags: eclipse, plugins, submenu, popupmenu

I am trying to add a popup item into "open with" menu of eclipse from org.eclipse.ui.menus extenstion point.
Basically I need to show this submenu on selection of particular type of object from the navigation view tree.

If anyone can guide me , it would be helpful . I have googled about it no specific answer

Comment: Open With... is a special menu built dynamically, I don't think you can add to it using normal extension points. The source is `org.eclipse.ui.actions.OpenWithMenu`

Comment: thanks the reply, 2 @greg-449. Any idea how can I acheive this if not possible with normal extenstion points

Comment: The only thing that menu will display is editors registered for the file content type. I don't know of any way to change that. You can read the source to see exactly what it does.